# HSQLDB is stop doing periodic CHEKPOINT operation and log files is keep growing

Tags: hsqldb

We are using hsqldb (2.2.8) as in-memory database for our web application which is running on tomcat web server (6.19). We have set the max size of the log file to hsqldb.log_size=200 (which is 200 MB),

but for some instances of out production environment the log file (~/tomcat/work/hypersonic/localDB.log) is growing way beyond that range (40GB).

Further looking into the logs we found that the DB stop performing the CHECKPOINT operation. What is the default behaviors of HSQL DB in performing periodic CHECKPOINT operation ? Is there anyway we can stop growing this LOG file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the size of the .log reaches its limit, the CHECKPOINT operation is performed when all connections to the database have committed. You may have a connection that has not been committed.

You can check the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SYSTEM_SESSIONS table and see if there is a session in transaction. You can reset such sessions with the ALTER SESSION statement.

http://www.hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/sessions-chapt.html

Comment: Thanks for your response. Do you think it is because of some long running SQLs ? Also do you think running ALTER SESSION once fix the problem (I mean, do we have to run this each time or do you suspect some long pending/stuck transaction creating all these issue...? Finally could you please give some example of ALTER SESSION statements)

Comment: I ran a SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SYSTEM_SESSIONS, it lists the 10 active sessions with all the sessions shows its TRANSACTION column as "false", except the one in which I am executing the query. So this really confuses me on which session to close. Also the WAITING_FOR_THIS, THIS_WAITING_FOR also returns empty.

Comment: In that case it is an anomaly. Try performing CHECKPOINT when you connect.